# Android GTM: Possible to start new Google Analytics session manually?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So I'm working on implementing the latest Google Tag Manager into my application for use with Google Analytics. It's in place and everything is working great, but I do have a question.

Is it possible to manually start a new session within GA while using GTM to fire all of the events? For example, when I user logs out I would like to begin a new session, can I force that to happen using GTM?

Thanks!

OSFTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [`sessionControl`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference?hl=en#session) config var.

In GTM, in your GA tag config, it's under

**More Settings** `>` **Fields to Set**

Click the **Add Field** button, then for **Field Name** put `sessionStart` and for **Value** put "end" to force end of the current session or "start" to force (re)start of session.

**Notes:**

If you are using a `Web` **Container Type**, this is only available for `Universal Analytics` **Tag Type**. The `Classic Google Analytics` **Tag Type** does not have an equivalent, though you can maybe do some magic with [_setSessionCookieTimeout](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration?hl=en#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSessionCookieTimeout) if you're feeling ambitious.

If the GTM container is created as `Mobile` **Container Type**, it will only show `Google Analytics` as a **Tag Type** option, but this is a misnomer. Under the hood, GTM uses the **Measurement Protocol** for `Mobile` containers, and `sessionControl` is available for that.

Comment: I figured the solution would end up being something like this! Thanks!

Comment: @CrayonViolent how do we trigger the event of ending the session?